# Why is the driver object defined, but the webdriver object is not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

### Question

Why does driver work fine(the title is retrieved and tested), but web driver is undefined(unable to getText)?

### Expected Result

The tests will complete successfully.

### Actual Result

```
 ․ Google  when at home Page should have correct title: 141ms
  1) Google  when at home Page when searching should input search term

  1 passing (3s)
  1 failing

  1) Google  when at home Page when searching should input search term:
     ReferenceError: webdriver is not defined
```

### Files Used

#### Test File

Used to run the tests by executing command: `mocha -t -R list index.js` (assuming index.js is the filename)

```
var fs            = require('fs'),
    chai          = require('chai'),
    assert        = chai.assert,
    expect        = chai.expect,
    test          = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
    webdriver     = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    Page          = require('./pageobjects/pages/home');

test.describe('Google', function(){

    test.before(function(){
        driver = new webdriver.Builder().
                withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).
                build();

        //initialize driver and webdriver on the Page Object
        Page.webdriver = webdriver;
        Page.driver = driver;
    });

    test.describe("", function () {
        test.before(function(){
          //console.log(Page);
        });

        test.describe("when at home Page", function () {
          test.before(function () {
            Page.get(Page.URL);
          });

          test.it("should have correct title", function () {
            Page.getTitle()
            .then(function (title) {
              assert.equal(title, 'Google');
            });
          });

          test.describe("when searching", function () {
            test.it("input search term", function () {
              Page.sendKeys(Page.Search.INPUT, 'test');
              Page.getText(Page.Search.INPUT)
              .then(function (text) {
                assert.equal(text, 'test');
              });
            });
        });

        test.after(function () {
            driver.quit();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

#### Page

object used to create pages

```
var Page = {
  getTitle : function getTitle() {
    return driver.getTitle();
  },
  get : function get(url) {
    return driver.get(url);
  },
  sendKeys : function sendKeys(element, text) {
    console.log(webdriver);
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css(element)).sendKeys(text);
  },
  click : function click(element) {
    return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css(element)).click();
  }
};

module.exports = Page;
```

#### Home

object that represents a page, uses mixins to get Page's functions
the search file is left out because it is irrelevant to the problem

```
var Page = require('./page'),
    Search = require('../components/search'),
    extend = require('extend');

var Home = {
  URL : 'http://google.com',
  Search : Search
};
module.exports = Home;

//extend home with page
extend(module.exports, Page);
```

Comment: webdriver isn't defined in Page.sendKeys. Are you expecting it to exist globally?

Comment: @TheDeveloper i was thinking it would be reachable since i set Page.webdriver to the webdriver object in the test file. Why does Page.driver work fine, but Page.webdriver does not?

ty for the quick reply :)

Comment: Because driver has no preceding `var` keyword so is being defined in the global scope (which is a bad pattern and almost always not what you want). Access the properties using Page.driver and Page.webdriver, or refactor Page putting the methods on the prototype and use `this`.